# Calculating Games Played and Won from ArrayFormula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas, sumifs

I am running into some issues when trying to take a table of games, and output a sorted list of matches played and points earned using the standard win=3 points, draw=1 point, loss=0 points.

| ---- | Hermione | Harry | Ron | Neville |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hermione | - | Harry | Hermione | Hermione |
| Harry | Harry | - | Harry | Harry |
| Ron | Hermione | Harry | - |  |
| Neville | Hermione | Harry |  | - |

Quick issue: If I take the simple conversion in `=IF(B2=$A2,3,IF(B2=B$1,1,0))` and try to expand it to an arrayformula to get an intended result of {0,1,3,3} `=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:R2=$A2,3,IF(B2:R2=B$1,1,0)))` it only evaluates the first if condition and outputs {0,0,3,3}.

I have not found a good way to sum the values across each row iteratively, and include logic for pointing like above. Using SumIf or a Query it wants to evaluate the entire range for each criterion:
`={unique(A2:A5),ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(B2:E5,unique(A2:A5),G2:J5))}`
[image: first]

I can work around this by creating a filtered list `={"Player";unique(filter(A2:A5,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A5))))}`

Then account for it checking the entire section instead of going row by row with some quick math `={"Played","Points";ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(B2:E5,A2:A5)/2),ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(B2:E5,A2:A5)*1.5)}` but this still leaves us unable to count the number of games played accurately and with no options for a draw in the points totals.
[image: workaround]

The intended output would be:

| Player | Played | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hermione | 3 | 6 |
| Harry | 3 | 9 |
| Ron | 2 | 0 |
| Neville | 2 | 0 |

and if Ron and Neville were to play their last game of the 3 and draw it would update to:

| Player | Played | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hermione | 3 | 6 |
| Harry | 3 | 9 |
| Ron | 3 | 1 |
| Neville | 3 | 1 |

The idea would be to have both the player names, the games played, and points accrued in a sortable list (personal goal is to get it on one line because why not)

Please let me know what I am missing!

Comment: D7:F11 is your desired output or A7:B11 ?

Comment: also explain your score system in more detail. F8 should be just 3 and F10 should be only 6 coz if we go row-wise or column-wise there is only 1 victor per row/column (unless there is a draw)

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get unique players, the games they played and points
 Adjust the range `A1:E` if necessary

```
=ArrayFormula({SPLIT("Player,Played,Points",",");
  QUERY(QUERY({LAMBDA(r,QUERY({SPLIT(INDEX(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(r,1,COLUMNS(r))), " Offset 1")))&"|"&TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY({r}, "Select Col1 where Col1 <> '' Offset 1")))),"|"),FLATTEN(
 FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({r}, " Select * where Col1 <> '' Offset 1 ")), " Offset 1 " ))))}," Where Col1<>Col2 "))
 (A1:E)}, " Select min(Col1),count(Col2),count(Col3) Group by Col1")," offset 1",0)} )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[result_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw9KE.png)

[result_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHQiP.png)

Use COUNTA with FILTER to calculate the "Played" values,

use SUMPRODUCT with FILTER to get the "Win" values,

use SUM with INDEX / MATCH to calculate the "Draw and Lose" values,

use LAMBDA to make the formulas easier to read,

use SPLIT and BYROW to pack everything up into one cell.

```
=ArrayFormula(
SPLIT(BYROW(A8:A11,
  LAMBDA(ROW,
   LAMBDA(TOP,LEFT,DATA,
    (COUNTA(FILTER(DATA,LEFT=ROW))+COUNTA(FILTER(DATA,TOP=ROW)))&","&
    ((SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(DATA,LEFT=ROW)=ROW,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(DATA,TOP=ROW))=ROW)*3)
    +SUM(INT(((INDEX(DATA,XMATCH(ROW,LEFT,0))<>"")*(INDEX(DATA,XMATCH(ROW,LEFT,0))=ROW))<>TRANSPOSE((INDEX(DATA,,XMATCH(ROW,TOP,0))<>"")*(INDEX(DATA,,XMATCH(ROW,TOP,0))=ROW)))))
   )(B1:E1,A2:A5,B2:E5)
  )
 ),",")
)
```